# ExpressJS Multer File Persmission

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer  = require('multer');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(multer({ dest: '/new/'}));
```

This is starting of file. It is always showing below message during startup the server

> /usr/lib/node_modules/multer/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:90
>                       throw err0;
>                             ^ Error: EACCES, permission denied '/new'
>       at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:654:18)
>       at Function.sync (/usr/lib/node_modules/multer/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
>       at new DiskStorage (/usr/lib/node_modules/multer/storage/disk.js:21:12)
>       at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/multer/storage/disk.js:65:10)
>       at new Multer (/usr/lib/node_modules/multer/index.js:15:20)
>       at multer (/usr/lib/node_modules/multer/index.js:75:12)
>       at Object. (/var/www/node/server.js:10:9)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)

Please let me if someone can help me to prevent this problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 10):

multer is trying to create a destination folder **/new** in global node_modules location. Change your path to local destination. Try the following

```
app.use(multer({ dest: './new/'}));
```

if you are getting error with the above try

```
app.use(multer({ dest: __dirname +'/new/'}));
```

Comment: These are giving me this error: TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions

Comment: @EmamulAndalibAyon have you tried Krzysztof Sztompka answer?

Comment: Adding dirname just solved the issue I've been dealing with for 3 hours. Thanks Ram !!!

Answer (score 5):

You have two isues:

1) You set global destination path to multer. And multer has not permission to create that path (and it is correct). I suspect you want to create 'new' directory in your project, if yes, then change your path to './new/'. When you fix this then we have second problem.

2) Multer module change API. It will not work:

```
app.use(multer({ dest: './new/'}));
```

unless you have an old version of multer (dont use old version it has security isues). Check docs page for how to use multer: [link](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). You can check my answer to similar problem: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592428/express-js-node-js-multer-intergration-issue/32595842#32595842). In short:

configure destination path:

```
var upload = multer({ dest: './new' })
```

then in each route where you want to upload file

```
app.post('/profile', upload.single('fieldname'), function (req, res, next) {
//req.file has data of uploaded file
}
```